# Menus editor show language tags in wordpress 3.6 (qTranslate)

Tags: wordpress, qtranslate

After upgrade to wordpress 3.6 and qTranslate Version: 2.5.36. It shows the language tags in menus editor. How can I deal with this issue?

```
<!--:fi-->Tämä on testi sivu<!--:--><!--:sv-->Detta är en testsida<!--:--><!--:en-->This is a test page<!--:-->
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an [old issue](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-qtranslate-translating-nav-menu?replies=17). And can be solved with this snippet:

```
function qtrans_menuitem( $menu_item ) {
    $menu_item->title = qtrans_useCurrentLanguageIfNotFoundUseDefaultLanguage( $menu_item->title );
    return $menu_item;
}
add_filter( 'wp_setup_nav_menu_item', 'qtrans_menuitem', 0 );
```

<sub>Reference: [Where do I put the code snippets I found here or somewhere else on the web?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/72160/12615)</sub>